# When invoked "notifyDataSetChanged() "of the RecyclerView Adapter,RecyclerView throw "java.lang.Throwable: addInArray "

Tags: java, android

Activity, There is a RecyclerView in the activity, get data by getGroupList(), this is an asynchronous method.

```
public void getSelectGroupList() {
    getGroupList(getGroupList_listener);
}

private LogicTaskListener<UserGroupModel> getGroupList_listener = new     LogicTaskListener<UserGroupModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(UserGroupModel result) {
            loadingFinish();
            if (result.code == KoalaHttpStatus.OK) {
                mAdapter.setData(result.data.list);
            }
        }
    };
```

Adapter, Update data by setData method, when invoked setData() notifyDataSetChanged(), throw java.lang.Throwable: addInArray

```
public void setData(List<UserGroupBean> data) {
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Throwable information :

> addInArray been called, this = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{4295f4f0 VFED.... .F....ID 40,218-1240,780 #7f0d00ca app:id/select_group_recyclerview}call stack =
>                                                                    java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3786)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3740)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3564)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3509)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:649)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7112)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7070)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7058)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1428)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)
>                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3568)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
>                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
>                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
>                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.jav

Comment: show your code please

Comment: add code and Exception info

Comment: Please add code of your Adapter and layout xml of your list items.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use RecyclerView's Adapter for notifyDataSetChanged(), when data for RecyclerView has been changed and need to update.

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: the setData() method in the RecyclerView's Adapter,

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that your adapter link is initialize before you give assign the list from fragment or activity

its issue when you assign

```
 List<UserGroupBean> data = new ArrayList<>() ;  //adapter
```